# Getting cookies from Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently using InAppBrowser plugin in an Ionic Cordova app and trying to get the request cookies from the InAppBrowser itself using below codes without success. The cookie is always empty.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
    ref.executeScript({ code: "document.cookie" }, function (cookie) {
        alert(cookie);
    });
});
```

More information:
 - Cordova version 6.0.0
 - InAppBrowser plugin version 1.2.1
 - Visual Studio 2015
 - VS Android Emulator KitKat
 - Cookie is not httpOnly cookie

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies in Cordova are accessed very differently that a typical web app. The WebView your app runs in is sandboxed so that all Cookies are accessed via a singleton class. In iOS its `NSHTTPCookieStorage`. Not the normal `document.cookie` object. In oder to access cookies in Cordova you'll need to find/develop a plugin which interfaces to this native Object.